# Como filtrar um Texto em uma div com angular JS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, filtro

O problema consiste em montar um filtro em AngularJS pra capturar palavras, querys, dentro de um texto, por exemplo como se fosse pesquisar uma palavra em um ofício.

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="namesController">

<p><input type="text" ng-model="test"></p>

<div ng-????="filter:test>
   <p> {{ texto }} </p>
</div>


</div>
```

Comment: Mas de onde vem essas palavras que você quer filtrar? De um `ng-init`? - [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o proprio filter do angular

#### HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <label>Filtrar: <input ng-model="searchText"></label>
    <div ng-repeat="user in users | filter:searchText">
      <p>
      Nome : {{user.nome}} -
      Idade : {{user.idade}}
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Javascript

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.users = [];
    $scope.users.push({'nome':"Francisco", 'idade': 94});
    $scope.users.push({'nome':"Raimunda", 'idade': 85});
    $scope.users.push({'nome':"Francinaldo", 'idade': 77});
    $scope.users.push({'nome':"Tereza", 'idade': 87});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal resolvi o problema com o código abaixo:

[Filter PHP list with angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19040732/filter-php-list-with-angularjs)

[Veja aqui o código no plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bv2opi5CHfJa0pQyFrBc?p=preview)

Acontece que estou tendo problemas com as palavras que são capitalizadas por exemplo, uma palavra que está "Protocolo" e eu digito "protocolo", o filtro não encontra ela.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.model = {
        filter: ''
    };
});

app.directive('myHtmlFilter', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          filter: '=myHtmlFilter',
          element: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          scope.$watch('filter', function(newval, oldval) {
            elem
              .find('ul>li')
                  .hide()
                  .find(scope.element)
                  .filter(':contains("'+scope.filter+'")')
               .parent()
                  .show();
          })
        }
    }
}]);
```

Index.html

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model.filter" />

<div my-html-filter="model.filter" element="h2">
  <ul>
    <li id="1">
        <h2>Protocolo</h2>
        <p>The Message...</p>
    </li>
    <li id="2">
        <h2>My second Post</h2>
        <p>The Message...</p>
    </li>
    <li id="3">
        <h2>My third Post</h2>
        <p>The Message...</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Também não consegui deixar a busca 'insensitive' com o Angular, dae fiz pelo Jquery base com [Fonte](http://www.devmedia.com.br/filtrando-listas-html-com-jquery/26398) e usando o javascript da seguinte forma:

```
$(function(){
                $("#txtBusca").keyup(function(){
                        var texto = $(this).val().toUpperCase();

                        $(".ulItens li").css("display", "block");
                        $(".ulItens li").each(function(){
                                if($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(texto) < 0)
                                   $(this).css("display", "none");
                        });
                });
        });
```

`.ulItens` -> com a classe aplico em todas as tags `<ul>` e com o toUpperCase consigo fazer a busca sem o case sensitive padrão.

Comment: Mas vi aqui que você encontrou a resposta nesse outro link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48972/problema-com-uppercase-e-lowercase-no-angularjs Valeu!! :D