# Problema com Uppercase e Lowercase no Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, filtro, filter

Pessoal segui o exemplo de um script no stackoverflow.com como segue o link abaixo:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19040732/filter-php-list-with-angularjs][1]

Acontece que estou tendo problemas com as palavras que são capitalizadas por exemplo, uma palavra que está "Protocolo" e eu digito "protocolo", o filtro não encontra ela.

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.model = {
        filter: ''
    };
});

app.directive('myHtmlFilter', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          filter: '=myHtmlFilter',
          element: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          scope.$watch('filter', function(newval, oldval) {
            elem
              .find('ul>li')
                  .hide()
                  .find(scope.element)
                  .filter(':contains("'+scope.filter+'")')
               .parent()
                  .show();
          })
        }
    }
}]);
```

**Index.html**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model.filter" />

<div my-html-filter="model.filter" element="h2">
  <ul>
    <li id="1">
        <h2>Protocolo</h2>
        <p>The Message...</p>
    </li>
    <li id="2">
        <h2>My second Post</h2>
        <p>The Message...</p>
    </li>
    <li id="3">
        <h2>My third Post</h2>
        <p>The Message...</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: [Nessa outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48755/como-filtrar-um-texto-em-uma-div-com-angular-js) você postou uma solução. Seria a mesma resposta para essa pergunta?

Comment: Não, nesta caso o problema consiste em realizar uma pesquisa onde quando digita-se uma palavra e a mesma corresponda aos valores encontrados independente se é maiúscula ou minúscula.

Answer (score 3):

O problema está na linha:

```
.filter(':contains("'+scope.filter+'")')
```

O seletor [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) do jQuery faz distinção entre letras maiúsculas e minúsculas (case sensitive). A função [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) aceita como parâmetro um callback que você pode usar para avaliar se o elemento atende aos seus critérios e se deve ou não ser adicionado à lista dos itens filtrados.

Um exemplo de callback que faz uma comparação case insensitive:

```
.filter(function(){ return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(scope.filter) > -1 })
```

Na sua diretiva ficaria assim:

```
app.directive('myHtmlFilter', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          filter: '=myHtmlFilter',
          element: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          scope.$watch('filter', function(newval, oldval) {
            elem
              .find('ul>li')
                  .hide()
                  .find(scope.element)
                  .filter(function(){ return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(scope.filter) > -1 })
               .parent()
                  .show();
          })
        }
    }
}]);
```